# Как открыть для Интернета сайт, запущенный в docker?

Tags: nginx, docker

Пытаюсь запустить контейнер Docker с nginxом. Запускаю на сервере, 3000 порт. Ввожу ip_сервера:3000, сайт не работает. Внутри контейнера же всё в порядке. С другими портами так же

Как можно открыть доступ к сайту, запущенному в контейнере через Интернет?

Comment: Пробросить порт внтурь контейнера - это сделано? Зайдите на сервер. `curl -v http://localhost:3000` что выводит?

Answer (score 0):

Опубликуйте порт 3000.

Если вы используете docker-compose, то добавьте в docker-compose.yml:

```
ports:
  - "3000"
```

Подробности [тут](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports).

Если вы не используете docker-compose, то читайте [тут](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports).